# Only one selection showing in drop down list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

I am trying to display seven days from today's date in a Tkinter option menu, but when I run the script only one day gets printed.

When I print as per the code all seven days show in print but not on Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

master = Tk()

#Gets date from host computer and prints 7 days
date = datetime.now()
for x in range(7):
   d = date - timedelta(days=x)
   print(d.strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y"))


#Add the date to the tkinter window
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("Select Date") # default value
w = OptionMenu(master, value=d.strftime("%A%d/%m/%Y"),variable= variable)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Using Python 3.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: You have provide only one date to `value` option of `OptionMenu`, so there should be only one item in the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - maybe you can help when "print(d.strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y"))" i get a total of 8 days displayed. 

But when i add it to the OptionMenu i just get the one date displayed. 

How do i get all 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all computed values of `d` and pass them to `OptionMenu`.

```py
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

master = Tk()

# Gets date from host computer and prints 7 days
date = datetime.now()
dates = []
for x in range(7):
    d = date - timedelta(days=x)
    dates.append(d.strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y"))
    print(d.strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y"))


# Add the date to the tkinter window
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("Select Date")  # default value
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *dates)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? It raises exception.

Comment: Hi , this code does print the dates in the list. However i need in the format the same as print which is where i am struggling. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: w = OptionMenu(master, value=d.strftime("%A%d/%m/%Y"), variable=variable, *d)

TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not datetime.datetime

Comment: Sorry. For some reason I added the wrong code in the final answer. It is fixed now. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

master = Tk()

# Gets date from host computer and prints 7 days
date = datetime.now()
dates = []
for x in range(7):
    d = date - timedelta(days=x)
    dates.append(d)
    print(d.strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y"))


# Add the date to the tkinter window
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("Select Date")  # default value
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *dates)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

and this version too:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

master = Tk()

# Gets date from host computer and prints 7 days
date = datetime.now()
dates = []
for x in range(7):
    d = date - timedelta(days=x)
    dates.append(d)
    print(d.strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y"))


def display_selected(choice):
    choice = variable.get()
    print('selected is : ', choice, type(choice))




# Add the date to the tkinter window
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("Select Date")  # default value
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *dates, command=display_selected)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

check the difference commenting out `choice = variable.get()`

in :

```
def display_selected(choice):
    choice = variable.get()
    print('selected is : ', choice, type(choice))
```

in the output of:

```
print('selected is : ', choice, type(choice))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the dates in a list and pass this list to `OptionMenu` instead:

```py
...
#Gets date from host computer and prints 7 days
date = datetime.now()
dates = []
for x in range(7):
    d = date - timedelta(days=x)
    dates.append(d.strftime("%A %d/%m/%Y"))
    print(dates[-1])

# Add the dates to the tkinter OptionMenu
variable = StringVar(master, value="Select Date")
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *dates)
w.pack()
...
```